# react components interface extends or seperate

Tags: reactjs

```
export interface checkBoxValueProps {
  label: string;
  fieldName?: string;
}

export interface checkBoxProps {
  type: "checkbox" | "radio";
  checkBoxContent: checkBoxValueProps;
  groupName: string;
  value: boolean;
  setValue: (value: boolean) => void ;
}

export interface CheckBoxInputGroupProps {
  checkBoxArray: checkBoxValueProps[];
  type: "checkbox" | "radio";
  groupName: string;
  value: Record<string, boolean>;
  setValue: (value: Record<string, boolean>) => void;
  showSelectAll?: boolean;
}
```

I have 2 components, one for handling single input and another one is for group up several input.

baseCheckbox have 2 interfaces:checkBoxValueProps  ,checkBoxProps

and groupedCheckBox have 1 interface: CheckBoxInputGroupProps

some of the fields like type and groupName are 100% repeated in borh interfaces while value and setValue are same just the type recived are different.. In this case, i am suggested to do like

export interface CheckBoxInputGroupProps extends checkBoxProps (but the type of value n setvalue might nid combine up) ? or let them become 2 different interfaces ?